# Is there a flavour of ubuntu for an orange pi 3?

Tags: arm

I know of Ubuntu IOT. It supports raspberry pi but doesn't say anything about the orange pi. There is a link on the orange pi website that takes you to a download you can get from google drive but I want to know if there is an official version of Ubuntu that is compatible with orange pi.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the Raspberry image on Orange Pi, as these microcomputers are compatible. But you can get issues with not working USB ports, WiFi. Better to download an image for your model of orange from http://www.orangepi.org/downloadresources/.